# Deprecated Gradle In React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

When I launch my app using my genymotion emulator with react native i got this error ?

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0

note : I use react native cli .

This is what appears :

[image]

I want to understand why this happened, plus i don't know about gradle

where i can find it and know its version,

and solve this problem with react native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that one or more Gradle build scripts is using a feature that is deprecated. You can check the list of deprecated features by looking at Gradle release notes for your current version (and probably previous versions as well).

The console output should tell you where the issue is coming from. If it's from a third-party dependency, you could either open a PR on the repo that needs to be updated, or ignore it as it won't affect your build.